# Advice on ML ideas/models for a data set I have

Tags: machine-learning, modeling, econometrics, marketing

I have a very large marketing data set (300GB in size) and I am wondering what ML models I can apply to it. The dataset consists of transactional data from supermarkets. The type of data I have is the following:

- There are 20 years worth of data, with 52 weeks in each year.
- 50 markets/regions
  -- Within each region there are approximately 20-40 stores.
  ---Each store sells approximately 40 different products (think; shampoo, toothpaste, chips, frozen pizza, beer etc.)
  ---- Each product consists of many brands
  ---- Each product has many characteristics
- For a few markets I have Panel level information where I can determine income, race, sex etc. (approx 1 million observations).

For the whole data set I estimate that there are approx 5-10 billion observations.

So I have 20 year time series transactional data for 50 different markets, with a lot of information on the products (type of packaging, Price, qty sold, glass bottle or tin can, colour, flavor etc.

What I have currently done:

- Apply a simple LSTM model to forecaste future sales for certain brands
- Apply XGBoost in order to classify which customers Will purchase a certain product

What I want:

- I am looking also for some more "economic" theory to be applied. It is great to apply ML in order to forecast sales etc. but I want to prove/disprove some economic theory. i.e. are certain customers (based on PANEL characteristics) more willing to buy a particular Brand than other customers. Do customers who shop at stores with fewer choice choose the same product as customers who shop at stores with a higher selection.

Ideas:

Could it be possible to apply reinforcement learning over a sequence (time) in this model?

At the moment I am just brainstorming some ideas so your advice, comments Will only add to future ideas.

My question is: Given this data set which ML model would you apply and to which problem?

I have some ideas myself but I want to know if there are better suggestions for such a data set.